# To match glob patterns in if statement starting with - (dash)

Tags: shell, posix

I am unable to match "--debug" in the if statement. 
I am targeting a POSIX compliant script.

```sh
CHANNELS=;
set -- stable beta dev master --debug

echo "DEBUG: Before while $@";
while [ $# -gt 0  ]; do
  echo "DEBUG: Inside while $1";
  if [ ! $1 = -* ]; then
    echo "DEBUG: Inside if $1";
    CHANNELS="$CHANNELS $1";
  fi
  shift;
done
echo "DEBUG: After while $CHANNELS";
```

Actual -> $CHANNELS has "stable beta dev master --debug" 
Expected -> $CHANNELS should have "stable beta dev master"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern matching is done with the `case` construct in POSIX shells:

```
CHANNELS=
set -- stable beta dev master --debug

echo "DEBUG: Before while $@";
while [ "$#" -gt 0  ]; do
  echo "DEBUG: Inside while $1";
  case $1 in
    (-*) ;;
    (*)
      echo "DEBUG: Inside case (*)"
      CHANNELS="$CHANNELS $1";;
  esac
  shift
done
echo "DEBUG: After while $CHANNELS";
```